# MS access to view all record history data with the specific input field value but it is showing only first record of criteria

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I tried to display a list of all requests from a specific dept of my table

So I created a form with all the tbl fields that I want to display on the form view of "details" section like this .

```
 dept name Totalnum req#  ticket
```

Then I have created a combo box with pre-defined values as 'depttest' field.

Then I used the following code on change value of field but form is displaying only the first record of the category and not showing all the records .... can some one please help me with this logic..

```
Option Compare Database

Option Explicit

'Set default record source of form

Const strsql = "SELECT tbl.dept,tbl.name,tbl.[Totalnum],tbl.[req#],tbl.[Ticket] FROM tbl"

Private Sub depttest_Change()

Dim strFilterSQL As String

strFilterSQL = strsql & " Where [dept] = 'me.depttest.value';"

Me.RecordSource = strFilterSQL

'DoCmd.RunSQL strFilterSQL

Me.Requery

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing `me.depttest.value` as a string not a value.  Try:

```
strFilterSQL = strsql & " Where [dept] = '" & me.depttest.value & "';"
```

Comment: Thank you so much Tony for your . I tried your syntax and it works But all records are not displaying at the same time. It seems I need to navigate the record 1,2...386 etc.. 

It looks I missed some thing to get this kind of view.. can you suggest what I you should include to get this view..

Thanks a million.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to define `Me.RecordSource` as the source for Combo Box.  I have only ever loaded List and Combo boxes with a loop around AddItem.  Sorry I can help further.

Comment: I got it where I had a problem..

I have the Result Data columns and my combo box input are both in "Details" section form ...

Now I changed my combox box input categories in Footer then works.. I all data displaying in the same form.. Thanks!